# ReactJS. Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s)

Tags: reactjs, compiler-warnings

I have warning from ReactJS

`Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s) 'level'`

How to fix my loop?
I don't know how to send ver level and change it in my infinity loop.

```
const catTree = [{"id": "963",
    "level": 1},
  {"id": "998",
    "level": 2},
  {"id": "1636",
    "level": 2}];
let cats = [];
let level = 1;
let catsCand = [];
for (; cats.length < 2;) {
  cats = catTree.filter((cat) => {
    return cat.level === level;
  });
  if (!catsCand.length) {
  // if all levels give less then 2 cats
    catsCand = cats;
  }
  level += 1;
  if (!cats.length) { // if level is not exists
    cats = catsCand;
    break;
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer:
Just move level var to "for" loop.

```
let cats = [];
// показать корень
let catsCand = [];
for (let level=1; cats.length < 2; level++) {
  cats = catTree.filter((cat) => {
    return cat.level === level;
  });
  if (!catsCand.length) {
  // если все уровни дадут меньше 2 категорий
    catsCand = cats;
  }
  if (!cats.length) { // если пошел несуществующий уровень
    cats = catsCand;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Debugging: ESLint Warning "Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to variable(s)...no-loop-func"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58816244/debugging-eslint-warning-function-declared-in-a-loop-contains-unsafe-reference)

Comment: Just so you know, that error message is coming from eslint. The documentation for the rule can be found at https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func