# Button click opens the wrong div

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following html for 3 dropdown checklists (The anchor span is clicked to make the unnumbered list visible)

```js
for (var checkList of document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-check-list')) { 
   checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
   if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
      checkList.classList.remove('visible');
   else
      checkList.classList.add('visible');
   }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 357px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}   
.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Expired Metadata<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>

<div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Unregistered Groups<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>

<div id="list3" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Unregistered Teams<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>
```

However, when I click any of the anchor spans it only opens the last list (div.list3). The spans do not correspond to the correct list. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Note that [`classList.toggle('visible')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle) does the same thing as the whole `if/else` block you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`checkList` is a `var` which does not stay the same after the first iteration, yet, you're expecting to be a local constant variable that's used in *another scope* (wrapped in a function, executed on clicks).

You have to change the variable to either be of type `let`, as such, scoped in the local spectrum, or make another variable within the iteration to keep it in the memory.

```js
for (let checkList of document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-check-list')) { 
   checkList.getElementsByClassName('anchor')[0].onclick = function(evt) {
   if (checkList.classList.contains('visible'))
      checkList.classList.remove('visible');
   else
      checkList.classList.add('visible');
   }
}
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 357px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}   
.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}
.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Expired Metadata<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>

<div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Unregistered Groups<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>

<div id="list3" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Unregistered Teams<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Appendum, see [What's the difference between using “let” and “var”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Answer (score 0):

First of All:
Function declared in a loop contains unsafe references to 'checkList' variables... you can read more about it here:
[Function declared contains unsafe references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46538640/jshint-error-functions-declared-within-loops-referencing-an-outer-scoped-varia)

Second of All:
when you define a variable with `var` keyword, it does not stay the same after the first iteration... should use `let`

Third of All:
or you can use this snippet for **JS part** and it does not have those issues:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-check-list').forEach(item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', event => {
       if (item.classList.contains('visible')){
      item.classList.remove('visible');
       }
   else{
     item.classList.add('visible');
   }
  }
)
})
```

Answer (score -1):

try this snippet bellow.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-check-list').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  evt.currentTarget.classList.toggle('visible');
}))
```

```css
.dropdown-check-list {
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-check-list .anchor {
  margin-top: 6px;
  width: 357px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 5px 50px 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.dropdown-check-list ul.items {
  padding: 2px;
  display: none;
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-top: none;
}

.dropdown-check-list.visible .items {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="list1" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Expired Metadata<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>

<div id="list2" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Unregistered Groups<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>

<div id="list3" class="dropdown-check-list" tabindex="100">
  <span class="anchor">Unregistered Teams<span class="count">20</span></span>
  <ul class="items"> ... </ul>
</div>
```